# Error 0x801c0002 while joining Azure AD in hybrid mode

Tags: azure, directory, azure-active-directory

I am getting some issues with my lab setup. I am getting `0x801c0002 error` when I try to register my windows 10 devices in hybrid active directory mode.

I have attached the debug log and snippets.

Is there anyone who has experienced similar issue or know more about the error, Please help.

Regards
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Azrue AD Connect, make sure that any Organizational Units (OU) that contain the computer objects that need to be hybrid AD joined are enabled for sync in the Azure AD Connect sync configuration, or the OU is in the scope of the Azure AD Connect.

And then you could manually trigger the delta sync.

Comment: I tried doing manual suync but not changed. error remains the same.

Comment: For your issue, you could create a support request from the Azure portal. For the details, you could refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request.